# Como obtener el Id de un Ion select

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic

como estan? tengo el siguiente problema
estoy usando un ion-select

```
 <ion-item >
          <ion-label>Categoria</ion-label>
          <ion-select>
            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let c of categorys; let i=index">{{c.name}}</ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

el problema es el siguiente, como puedo obtener el ID del select seleccionado= ya que el ion-select-option no tiene ningun evento, y en el ion-select no puedo obtenerlo porque está antes del *ngFor.
Como puedo hacer para obtener el id para luego poder almacenar en la base de datos.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

podrías usar el [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) para hacer el binding con una variable, o podrías también usar un control de [formulario reactivo](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) para obtener el valor.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ion-select placeholder="Selecciones Categoria"  id="categoria" name="categoria"[(ngModel)]="publicacion.categoria" (ionChange)="obtenerValor($event)">
      <ion-select-option value="1">Eventos</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="2">Servicios</ion-select-option>
   <ion-select-option value="3">Dato Útil</ion-select-option>
   <ion-select-option value="4">Otros</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

**funcion para detectar IDs**

```
 obtenerValor(e){
  console.log(e.detail.value)
   this.idCategoria = e.detail.value;
  }
```